# Two kyocera printers have the same SysObjectID (.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2)

Tags: snmp, printers, mib

I am trying to get the device details of a printer using SNMP. I am trying to use the SysObjectID of the device for tracking the model. I am getting same value for SysObjectID (value of .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0) for the below printers,I checked it using a mib browser. I assume that every model of printers must share a unique Object id.

Kyocera FS-C5350DN

Kyocera TASKalfa 3050ci

I thought that OID is always unique between models, but how can this be possible? Am i wrong? Please suggest.

Comment: "I assume that every model of printers must share a unique Object id" I don't think every vendor of SNMP devices follows this.

Answer (score 1):

Try to base your model recognition on some additional information - for example sysDescription usually contains details about particular device variant.

Answer (score 0):

An OID is a particular point in a MIB. If you are querying `1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2` then it should give you a value like `1.3.6.1.4.1.9.1.1024` which, if you then look it up is `catalyst3560v248ts` That OID (ending in .1.1.2) is the reference or pointer to the place with the product ID essentially. Who's to say that both these printers don't use the same OIDs? Maybe one is just a hevier duty version of the other? I dont know, but what I've had success with in the past is querying `1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1` (instead of .1.1.2) and grabbing out what I need from there.

Basically, these probably just run some same version of something in their firmware that is the same version. You can often times find individual manufacturers having a Model Number OID within their MIB. You can contact the manufacturer or check their support page for that.